# Why can't you view the upvotes/downvotes on a meta question/answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, meta, up-votes

Is there a reason for that you can't view the number of upvotes and downvotes on a question/answer on a meta SE, but you can on the main SE sites?

Comment: You can use this userscript to enable this, even without the required rep: http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can. If you have enough reputation on the Meta site.

It is one of the [privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) - in particular [Established User](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user), which kicks in at 1000 reputation.

Comment: Note that MSO is the _only_ meta with its own reputation system.  For users who start on another site, the current behavior may be surprising.

Comment: @JonEricson - On other sites, the meta reputation is the same as the site reputation. My phrasing was very careful.